# How to share/attach image from server in gmail in android

Tags: android

I have a image gallery where images are coming from server. I want to share/attach image in gmail. I am using "Adding an Easy Share Action". 
http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html#set-share-intent

Initially i tried to share the image from my SDCard and i was able to do it by using below code.

```
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/DCIM/Camera/20130503_133024.jpg"));
     mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(sharingIntent);
```

When i tried to pass my server image url by using below code then while sending email i got message saying that "could not attach image".

Uri.parse("http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-jZgveEqb6pg/T3R4kXScycI/AAAAAAAAAE0/xQ7CvpfXDzc/s1024/sample_image_01.jpg")

Please help me to share the image from server.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the STREAM and EXTRA_STREAM intent types are not really well defined and ultimately depend on how the target app interprets them.
If you want to assure the image as a binary to be in the email, the safer way will be to download the image from the server an attach it to the intent yourself.
There's more light about the topic in here: ["android.intent.extra.STREAM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857148/android-intent-extra-stream)

Answer (score 0):

**After spent lot of time, finally I found solution:**

```
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(imageurl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            input = connection.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Bitmap immutableBpm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        Bitmap mutableBitmap = immutableBpm.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        View view  = new View(this);
        view.draw(new Canvas(mutableBitmap));
        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mutableBitmap, "rbt", null);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"test.android@gmail.com"});
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        intent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");
        startActivity(intent);
```

And add below permission in **manifest.xml**

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**It is working perfect for me**